# Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

How can I add items in a list with `2 columns`? It adds the items just in the first column if I use `ListBox.AddItem`. I want to add items in the `2nd column` too.
Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By using the `List` property.

```
ListBox1.AddItem "foo"
ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = "bar"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now if I want to get that value how can I do it? I mean to get the value in the first column I do ListBox1.Value ... bot for the 2nd column?

Comment: @Andrei Ion In the same way. `List` is a property, works both ways.

Comment: Yes, I guessed that it has to be the same way but I won't know the row of the selected item... I know that the column is 1 but the row? I guess that ListBox1.ListCount-1 is the row when you add the value... how do I know what's the row when a Value is selected? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andrei Ion The selected index is `.ListIndex`. Please use the object browser instead of wanderng in the dark. Press F2. Find the property and press F1.

Comment: Thanks. I try to use the help and it helps me a lot but sometimes I really don't know what to search and then I use stackoverflow. Anyway... thanks a lot... it really helped me!

Comment: You find *complementary* explanations and how to overcome the `.AddItem` method's built-in limitation of 10 columns via *array* assignment at [Populate ListBox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528558/vba-excel-populate-listbox-with-multiple-columns/47531440#47531440)

Answer (score 3):

There is one more way to achieve it:-

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim list As Object
Set list = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1", "hello", True)
With list
    .Top = 30
    .Left = 30
    .Width = 200
    .Height = 340
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "100;100"
    .MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectExtended
    .RowSource = "Sheet1!C4:D25"
End With End Sub
```

Here, I am using the range C4:D25 as source of data for the columns. It will result in both the columns populated with values.

The properties are self explanatory. You can explore other options by drawing ListBox in UserForm and using "Properties Window (F4)" to play with the option values.

Comment: Not exactly the answer, but a more efficient method to add a multicolumn list.

Comment: This only works when using VBA in combination with Excel :)

Answer (score -6):

**select propety**

Row Source Type  => Value List

**Code :**

ListbName.ColumnCount=2

ListbName.AddItem "value column1;value column2"

Comment: This does not add any value to column 2.  The `AddItem` method takes a value and optional index (row index) as argument.

Comment: @DavidZemens since the rowSource type is "Value list" delimited strings are interpreted same as columns. above code from Kong will work.

Comment: @krishKM in which version of Excel? Using 2010, `Debug.Print ListBox1.RowSourceType` raises a "member not found" error. I can see it in the Locals window, but not in the Properties pane.

Comment: @krish there is no RowSourceType property on Listboxes (or Comboboxes) in Excel. You are probably thinking of Access.