# vba listbox multicolumn add

Tags: vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)

With MFC VC++ there are two controls, `ListBox` and `ListCtrl`. But with VBA it seems we have only `ListBox`.

I want to create a listbox with 2 columns (Company_ID, Company_Name).

Here is what I tried:

1. I created lstbox(control type ListBox)
2. Row source type = value list
3. I am taking value from user from two edit boxes and when user clicks "add" then it should be added to the listbox with 2 columns.

In the VBA code routine I added the following lines:

```
lstbox.ColumnCount = 2
lstbox.AddItem (Company_ID)
```

The following code is not working which seems to be related with adding column value:

```
lstbox.Column(1,lstbox.ListCount - 1) = Company_name
```

This gives error:

> Runtime error '424' object required.

Could anyone help with vba code to add to multi column listbox.

Answer (score 39):

Simplified example (with counter):

```
With Me.lstbox
    .ColumnCount = 2
    .ColumnWidths = "60;60"
    .AddItem
    .List(i, 0) = Company_ID
    .List(i, 1) = Company_name 
    i = i + 1

end with
```

Make sure to start the counter with *0*, not 1 to fill up a listbox.

Comment: Me only to add in case of a user form.