# what's the meaning of listcount -1

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I've been searching on the internet trying to find what the meaning of `listcount -1` is, but i can't seem to find the exact answer.

why is there `-1` beside the listcount? or `.list(.listcount -1,1)` what is that mean?

**edit**

example of the listcount

`.additem a.value`

`.list(.listcount -1, 1) = ws.cells(A,B).value`

this adds the value of `ws.cells(A,B)` to the listbox1 but i don't understand why/how?

or i found a `code` on the internet http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/multi-select-listbox.htm

i understand that the purpose of the code is "if one of the list is selected, then transfer the value of listbox into cells" but why is there `.Listbox1.Listcount -1`?

Comment: Your question needs more *context*

Comment: Shot in the dark. I'm using that as well and the reason is `listindex` of `listboxes` starts at `0` while list count of course gives you the `listcount` which starts from `1`. So when you access `items` on `listboxes` referenced to `listcount`, it should be less 1.

Comment: @L42 you should add that as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make things clearer, as I've said, `ListCount` starts at `1` when counting `ListBox` items or `List`.
But `ListBox Indexing` of those items or `List` starts at `0`.
In your example, you are trying to add an item or `List` in a `Multi-Column ListBox`.
Take a look at below example:

```
With me.ListBox1
    .Add "Item1"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = "Item2"
    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = "Item3"
End With
```

Above code populates a `ListBox` initially set with 3 columns.
This line `.Add "Item"` adds the first `List` in the `ListBox`.
But you need to populate the rest of the columns.
To access those columns, you use `.List` property with this syntax:

```
expression.List(pvargIndex, pvargColumn)
```

`pvargIndex` is the `ListBox ListIndex` and `pvargColumns` is the column number.
Remember that you already added 1 `item` using the `.Add` property and the `ListIndex` of that item is?

```
.ListCount - 1 'which is current item count in the ListBox less one equal to 0
```

To learn more about pupulating `ListBox`, check [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213962/vba-listbox-multicolumn-add) out.
Also see [HERE](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/05/10/populating-multi-column-listboxcombobox/).
Hope above helps you somehow.

Comment: As an additional, if you have "Headers" turned on, the header occupies Row 0