# if cell value 1 then listbox .listindex = value

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have the following code:

`If ws.cells(A,B).value = "1" then .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex,5) = Checkbox.name`

but it prompts an error and i'm not sure how to fix it

essentially, what i'm trying to achieve is that if the cell (A,B) has a value of 1 then insert a name of the checkbox into listbox, listindex of 5.

all other previous listindexes are added by the following code:

`.list(.listcount -1, 1) = ws.cells(C,D).value`

`.list(.listcount -1,1) = ws.cells (E,F).value`

Comment: Could you include more of your code? Also please include the specific error message.

Comment: Hi, I've answered one of your questions earlier [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976383/whats-the-meaning-of-listcount-1/22977404#22977404). Don't be confused with adding an item to a `ListBox` and populating `Columns` of an existing `Item` in a `multi-colum ListBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you populate a `ListBox` with items.

```
For i = 1 to 5
    With me.ListBox1
        .AddItem i
    End With
Next
```

So assuming you have `ListBox1` in `UserForm1`, this will result to:

[image]

Let's say you want to replace `5` by `6`, you use `.List` property like this:

```
Me.ListBox1.List(4, 0) = 6
```

**Syntax:** expression.List(pvargIndex, pvargColumn)
Again, when you use `.List` property, `Index` and `Column` is always 1 less the actual `Item` and `Column`.
Since we want to replace `5` by `6` in  a `ListBox` with 1 Column and 5 items in it, the `Index` of `5` is 4 and it's `Column` is 0.
The result would be:

[image]

Now, what if you have multiple-column `ListBox` and you want to populate those `Columns`.
Say `Column` 2 of our `ListBox1`, we use this code.

```
For i = 1 To 5
    With Me.ListBox1
        .List(i - 1, 1) = "Item" & i
    End With
Next
```

Take note of the `Index` which is `i - 1` and the `Column` which is `1` (actual column count -1) 
The result would be:

[image]

So let's go back to your question.
This line:

```
If ws.cells(A,B).value = "1" then .ListBox1.List(.ListBox1.ListIndex,5) = Checkbox.name
```

will fail since you are trying to populate `Column 6` of your `ListBox1` which I believe doesn't exist.
Also you used `.ListIndex` property which returns the currently selected item index.
I don't know where you are executing your code but initially, `.ListIndex` value is `-1` since it will only have value on runtime when the user get to select an Item.

Now these lines:

```
.list(.listcount -1, 1) = ws.cells(C,D).value
.list(.listcount -1, 1) = ws.cells(E,F).value
```

actually just replaces the last item second column value.
First it passes `ws.cells(C,D).Value` to it then overwrites it with `ws.cells(E,F).value`.
Hope this anwers some of your questions a bit.