# Adding rows in a MultiColumn ListBox

Tags: vba, excel

I'm messing around with VBA, especially with listboxes.

I've created a search button, that's using a find property (.Find) and searches whatever we've put in the textbox in it's data table.

It can add the search results to a listbox, but if we want the entire row from where search result is, how do we add it, instead of doing something like this [vba listbox multicolumn add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213962/vba-listbox-multicolumn-add)?
How can it be done, using VBA?
Is it even possible?
Else, is it possible without VBA?

**What is happening:**

```
Data table: a | b | c | d | e
            1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5
Search:   a 
Listbox : a

Search:   1 
Listbox : 1

Search:   2
Listbox : 2

Search:   d 
Listbox : d
```

**What I "want":**

```
Data table: a | b | c | d | e
            1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

Search:  a
Listbox: a | b | c | d | e

Search:  1
Listbox: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

Search:  2
Listbox: 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

Search:  d
Listbox: a | b | c | d | e
```

If it's needed I can provide the code I am using for testing the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items in a multicolumn listbox can be accessed using the `.List` member. This member accepts two parameters as input:

```
ListBox1.List(RowIndex, ColumnIndex)
```

*RowIndex*: The row index of the record we want to access. Note the rows in a listbox are zero based. Therefor the index of the first row is *0*.

*ColumnIndex*: The column index of the field we want to access. Note the columns in a multi column listbox are also zero indexed. Therefore the first column has an index of *0*.

For example :

```
'Assign values to the columns 
For i = 1 To 9
    ListBox1.AddItem 'Create a new row
    ListBox1.List(i - 1, 0) = i 'Fill the first column
    ListBox1.List(i - 1, 1) = i * 10 
    ListBox1.List(i - 1, 2) = i * 100 
    ListBox1.List(i - 1, 3) = i * 1000 
Next i
```

**Alternatively**

> but if we want the entire row from where search result is, how do we add it, instead of doing something like this vba listbox multicolumn add ?

Assuming you have a range object (e.g., `rngFound`) which represent the result of your `.Find`:

```
Me.ListBox1.Clear
Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = rngFound.Columns.Count
Me.ListBox.RowSource = rngFound.Address
```

Comment: Good explanation. I edited it also to include the option for using the `RowSource` method as an alternative.

Comment: @DavidZemens : thx for the edit, I forgot about `RowSource` as I haven't used it in few years! But nice completion and actual answer of the OP! ;)

Comment: I forget about it to because I do mainly PPT development anymore, I don't do much with Excel but I remember that one can be useful *if* your UserForm needs to be linked to the worksheet. The neat thing about that is then the ListBox will reflect changes to the worksheet, without having to explicitly "update" the `.List` property