# Access VBA - adding row with multiple columns

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to add a multiple column item to a ListBox in access using VBA. Can't for the life of me work out how to do it though. There seems to be multiple ways on the internet, none of them have worked for me.

Here's an example:

```
Sub AddMultipleColumn()
'Add multiple Columns to a listbox
ListBox1.Clear 'Make sure the Listbox is empty
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 3 'Set the column Amount
'Fill the Listbox
ListBox1.AddItem "Row Number 1" 'Additem creates a new row
ListBox1.List(0, 1) = "Column Number 2" 'List(x,y) X is the row number, Y the column number
ListBox1.List(0, 2) = "Column Number 3"
ListBox1.List(0, 3) = "Column Number 4"
End Sub
```

http://visiblevisual.com/jupgrade/index.php/general-net/77-multiple-columns

Here's my code (already configured to have three columns):

```
lst_TemplateEditorList.AddItem "1"
lst_TemplateEditorList.List(0, 0) = "1"
lst_TemplateEditorList.List(0, 1) = "2"
lst_TemplateEditorList.List(0, 2) = "3"
```

But I get the compile error "Method or data member not found" on "lst_TemplateEditorList.List" because there's no List method/property.

I found something that used "Column" instead of "List", but that didn't work, and a few have no argument with "AddItem" which causes an error too:

```
lst_TemplateEditorList.AddItem
lst_TemplateEditorList.Column(0, 0) = "1"
lst_TemplateEditorList.Column(0, 1) = "2"
lst_TemplateEditorList.Column(0, 2) = "3"
```

But most seem to suggest the first should work, eg:

[Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)

[vba listbox multicolumn add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213962/vba-listbox-multicolumn-add)

It seems like it should be so simple... but I'm stumped. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listboxes in Access have a different set of properties/methods than listboxes in other Office programs (there they belong to the "Microsoft Forms" object model)

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195480.aspx

In Access you simply add the multi-column data like you would in the `RowSource` property for `RowSourceType = Value List`, separated by semicolons.

```
With Me.lst_TemplateEditorList
    .AddItem "1;2;3"   ' first row
    .AddItem "4;5;6"   ' second row
End With
```

**Edit**

The Access 2010 Developer Help adds to the confusion: if you search for `List`, you get the **Forms**-Listbox and its properties, including `.List`. You have to look very closely to notice that you have left the `Access` realm and have entered the `Microsoft Forms` realm. German Access here, but you get the idea.

[image]