# Manipulate a listbox of 11 columns

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, userform

I've got a listbox of 11 columns. When I try to add data to one of the columns, I get an error.

`ListBox1.Column(10, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 13)`

I don't understand why this happens, the listbox on the userform has a **ColumnCount of 11**.

The **error** I'm getting:

> "Run-time error 380: Unable to set Column property. Invalid property value."

The value of the selected cell is "Group 16".

**More info:**

Code:

```
'adding this doesn't help
ListBox1.Clear
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 20

    While shtG.Cells(k, 1) <> ""
        If 'some long working condition Then

            frmTP.ListBox1.AddItem (shtG.Cells(k, kolID))
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(1, j) = shtG.Cells(k, kolVnm) & strSpace & shtG.Cells(k, kolTV) & strSpace & shtG.Cells(k, kolAnm)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(2, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 5)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(3, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 6)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(4, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 7)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(5, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 8)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(6, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 9)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(7, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 10)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(8, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 11)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(9, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 12)
            frmTP.ListBox1.Column(10, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 13)
            j = j + 1
        End If
        k = k + 1
    Wend
```

Comment: You can only use 10 columns if you use `.AddItem`. You need to put the data into an array and then assign that to the `.List` property of the control.

Comment: What's in shtG.Cells(k, 13) ? What's weird about that cell? If you comment out all the other assignments , does that one work or does it still break?

Comment: see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213962/vba-listbox-multicolumn-add). Answer was not marked, but it works.

Comment: Rory: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you maybe give me an example? Or do you just mean I should use .List instead of .Column?     
DelmerNicholson: There's nothing weird about the cell, it's just a string that says "Group 16"     
ScottHoltzman: Do they just mean I should use .List instead of .Column?

Comment: @Grafit - Yes, I think so. I tested it and worked very well :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of thing I mean (you could improve performance by loading the sheet data into an array to begin and processing that, and not resizing the array so often, but it would distract from the key idea here!):

```
Dim vData()
j = 0
While shtG.Cells(k, 1) <> ""
    If 'some long working condition Then
        ReDim Preserve vData(0 To 10, 0 To j)
        vData(0, j) = shtG.Cells(k, kolID).Value
        vData(1, j) = shtG.Cells(k, kolVnm) & strSpace & shtG.Cells(k, kolTV) & strSpace & shtG.Cells(k, kolAnm)
        vData(2, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 5)
        vData(3, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 6)
        vData(4, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 7)
        vData(5, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 8)
        vData(6, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 9)
        vData(7, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 10)
        vData(8, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 11)
        vData(9, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 12)
        vData(10, j) = shtG.Cells(k, 13)
        j = j + 1
    End If
Wend
frmTP.ListBox1.Column = vData
```

Comment: Excuse me for my late reaction. This works like a charm except for one thing. If my vData is empty I'm getting the same `runtime error 380` as before. I tried checking if my array is empty with: `If Len(Join(vdata)) <> 0 Then`, but with that statement I'm getting `runtime error 5: Invalid procedure call or argument`.

Comment: Just check the value of j