# How can I make a UserForm ComboBox that will populate named columns into a ListBox or TextBox as a list?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: Screenshot]

So I am currently trying to make an interactive inventory userform for our ambulance to streamline things. What I am trying to do is, is allow users to select an item from a ComboBox that references a location on our ambulance that would then populate a list of items into a ListBox that shows them 2 columns of info. The Quantity of the item and the Item name. Everything I am finding has to do with just filling a single text box with a single line of info. If you look at the picture above I would like to also have the data with the headers also showing the column for the qty and item description. I need help with the coding on to do this cause I cant find any VBA code on something like this. Screenshot added above to ind of get an idea of what I am trying to do.

The current code I have for this is:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
  If ComboBox1.Value = "Cabinet 1" Then
     ListBox1.AddItem Sheet5.Range("Cabinet_1")
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe `ListBox1.List = Sheet5.Range("Cabinet_1").Value` ?

Comment: Okay so that worked but how would I get the code to not include the blank cells in the columns additionally how do i get it to snake the columns

Comment: @Kenneth to give you an idea for your follow up question of not include blanks - you could add the specified range to an `Array` and then loop through tue array to remove blanks and finally write the array to the sheet in the desired location. Sorry i cant give you specific code at the moment but with a bit of google you should find an abundance of solutions for doing this.

Comment: @SamuelEverson I figured it out. I had my named range selected for the entire row so I went back an changed it to only the cells that had the data in it. No I just need to figure out how to snake the columns in the list so that there is no scrolling.

Comment: @kenneth ah even easier! With the 'snaking' i think a loop with a counter will be the best bet? Probably with an if statement checking if the counter value is > the max row before it starts from the top again?

Comment: @kenneth or this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11222439/9663006