# Add values from multiple cells to a Listbox and get the First selected value back

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using the below code to populate a (userform) listbox with items on loan based on a person's name(Column B). I need to also include the Item ID number as a reference for further functions. I am wondering what is the best approach to return two values from a row (Item name(Column C) and ID number(Column L)) based on a reference value (Person's name) into a listbox.

```
Private Sub cboName_Change()

    Me.ListItem.Clear

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Range
    Set ws = Worksheets("Loans")

       With ws
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       End With

        Set i = ws.Range("B1:A" & LastRow)

         With i
            Set c = .Find(cboName.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = c.Address
        Do
            Set c = .FindNext(c)
            ListItem.AddItem .Cells(c.Row, 3).Value

        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With

End Sub
```

If this question is very similar to others already asked (always getting in trouble for that), any direction would be appreciated - I may just need some context (very new at coding). Thanks!

Comment: will this work, `ListItem.AddItem .Cells(c.Row, 3).Value & ":" & .Cells(c.Row, 12).Value` ?

Comment: Listboxes can have multiple columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213962/vba-listbox-multicolumn-add

Comment: Thanks @Mikku, yes that works. However, I am wondering whether it may be more appropriate to use multiple columns within the listbox so that it is easier to refer to that value at a later time. Could those individual values be referred to later if separated by the " : " in the same listbox column?

Comment: Yes, both ways it will work. You can use `|` or `:` to concatenate as I commented. And later you can use `Split(value, "|")(0)` to access the first value. This is less complicated than using ListBox with Multiple columns, so usually I prefer this.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll see how that goes! Thanks a lot @Mikku - your help is appreciated!

Comment: @Mikku, is this the correct way of referencing? I am getting an out of range error `Find(Me.ListItem.Selected(Split(Value, ":")(0)))`

Comment: No. You have to replace the `Value` in split with variable that have string value. Basically the Value there means a string.

Comment: `Find (Split(Me.ListItem.Selected, ":")(0))`

Comment: @Mikku Right, sorry I completely missed that. If I run the code with a msgbox to display results, it simply returns 'true' instead of the ID number. Without the split, it returns the full concatenated value. Apologies for my lack of troubleshooting ability here.

Comment: This is working for me `Split(ListBox1.list(ListBox1.ListIndex), ":")(0)` where ListBox1 is the Listbox on Userform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'll put up an answer for you:

There are 2 ways for this

- **Use Multicolumn ListBox**
- **Concatenate you string**

Second one I ll describe here as i prefer this one.

So in your code use:   `ListItem.AddItem .Cells(c.Row, 3).Value & ":" & .Cells(c.Row, 12).Value`

Now to get the selected Item back use: `Split(ListItem.list(ListItem.ListIndex), ":")(0)`

So if you have `Name` in one cell & `Mikku` in the Other, Listbox will display

`Name:Mikku`

and the second Line of code will give you `Name`

---

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: That's great, thanks for that! But one issue, when multiple selections are made, only the last clicked value shows. So,  if I have two entries in the list say, `Mikku` and `Joel`, if i clicked on both values but 'Joel' was the last clicked, the message box would return `Joel Joel`

Comment: You will have to play with the code. I can't say that, unless I try. Try different scenarios, if it doesn't work out. Let me know, will find something that will work. Saving the Selected Results in a Array could be one.

Comment: Will do, thanks for all your help thus far - extremely appreciated. I'll see how I go.

Comment: I have tried adding this split function into an array but it seems to be giving me the same problem of doubling up on values. It's strange, because without using the split, the values show correctly when selected. I can send through current array code if it helps. Thanks once again for any advice!

Comment: @JoelMcWilliam ,, Probably you should ask a new Question. :)