# VBA: How to Create and Add Items to a multi-column ListBox?

Tags: vba, excel, listbox, multiple-columns

How do you create a new ListBox using VBA in excel and then add items to different columns via an array?

My application of the ListBox is to populate it with data in multiple columns and have it appear where the user last clicks. I just need help with the creating and adding to the multi-column listbox.

The only way I have been able to add a new Listbox is:

```
ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(400, 200, 100, 100).Select
With Selection
    .name = "ListBox1"
End With
```

This way I created the box and set the name of it so I could reference it later using:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("ListBox1")).Select
```

From here I would try to add a two dimensional array thinking it would populate the listbox in two seperate columns:

```
Dim strArray(2, 1) As Variant
    strArray(0, 0) = "Value 1"
    strArray(0, 1) = "Value 2"
    strArray(1, 0) = "Value 3"
    strArray(1, 1) = "Value 4"
    strArray(2, 0) = "Value 5"
    strArray(2, 1) = "Value 6"

With Selection
    .AddItem strArray
End With
```

I have researched that there is a setting called '.ColumnCount' but it produces a "Run-time error '438':" when i try to use this setting:

```
With Selection
    .ColumnCount = 2
End With
```

Currently, I am trying to avoid using a UserForm when using this ListBox but if that is the 'better' way of doing this procedure let me know.

Comment: have a read from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251814.aspx), plenty of examples, post back when you have issue to troubleshoot.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)

Comment: Another link to pharma scam (vba4all [dot] com)... please delete your comment, Meehow/@vba4all and replace with Wayback Machine saved copy.

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(400, 200, 100, 100).Select
With Selection
     .name = "ListBox1"
     .ListFillRange = "$A$2:$A$11"
End With
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(strArray)
```

Comment: This answer concerns VB.NET and shoud be deleted.