# Excel VBA - Populating multicolumn userform listbox from array. No data when array has only 1 item

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, listbox

i have the following function that im using to populate a userform listbox with data from an array:

```
Function PopulateListboxWithArray(lstbox As MSForms.ListBox, var As Variant)

With lstbox

    If Not IsEmpty(var) Then
    .Clear
        .list = Application.Transpose(var)
        .ListIndex = -1
    End If

End With

End Function
```

My listbox contains two columns with the following properties:

[image]

**PROBLEM**

The data in the array has an ID column and a lastname column. I dont want the user to see the ID column so ive set that column width to 0 in the form.

When i import data that has more than one row, the data shows up in the listbox as expected.

*However, when the array only contains one row of data, the listbox shows up blank !*

I have tried deleting the columnwidths in the image above and when i do so and reimport the one row of data, i get the ID and lastname stacked on top of one another. But ofcourse this is not the result i want.

I have even tried replacing `.list = Application.Transpose(var)` with `.list = var` to no avail.

What am i doing wrong here, or is there a better way to populate a listbox?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer in this post:[Adding item in listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)

I needed to use the `.List` property My function now looks like this:

```
Function PopulateListboxWithArray(lstbox As MSForms.ListBox, var As Variant)

With lstbox

    If Not IsEmpty(var) Then
            .Clear
        If UBound(var, 2) > 0 Then
            .list = Application.Transpose(var)
        Else
            .AddItem var(0, 0)
            .list(.ListCount - 1, 1) = var(1, 0)
        End If

    End If

End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit** to add more "background"

not so sure why you're using Application.Transpose()

```
    With lstbox
        If Not IsEmpty(var) Then
            .Clear
            If UBound(var, 1) = 1 Then
                .AddItem
                .List(0, 0) = var(1, 1)
                .List(0, 1) = var(1, 2)
            Else
'               .List = Application.Transpose(var)
                .List = var
            End If
            .ListIndex = -1
        End If
    End With
```

where I populated `var` in the following way:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim var As Variant

    With Worksheets("LB") '<--| change "LB" to your actual sheet name
        var = .Range("B1", .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value '<--| populate var with columns "A:B" cells values from row 1 down to column "A" last non empty row
    End With
    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2 '<--| set listbox columns count
        .ColumnWidths = "0;144" '<--| set listbox columns width
    End With
    PopulateListboxWithArray Me.ListBox1, var
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks for responding. The transpose is needed when multiple rows of data are returned. i did try the .list = var but that did not work. cheers

Comment: @Nick, you are welcome. I added some background as to how I populate `var` and have it working