# Remove Item from Excel Listbox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I need to remove items from a Listbox using data from Range under certain conditions. I don't want to delete data in the Worksheet the Listbox is based on.

Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
 Me.LstWSource.RowSource = ""

 If Len(rRange.Offset(1, 0).Formula) > 0 Then
    Set rRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(G_sNameReferenceS).Range(rRange.Offset(1, 0), rRange.End(xlDown))

 With Me.LstWSource
  .ColumnWidths = "28pt"
  .RowSource = rRange.Address
  .ListIndex = -1
  End With '>>>
End If

  '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  sRet = fG_SortingBasicS("lstYear", "DESC")
  '>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

  For i = Me.LstWSource.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1

   '>> current string condition to delete Item <<
   If Me.LstWSource.List(i) > CStr(Year(G_datJourTraitee)) Then
     Me.LstWSource.RemoveItem (i)
   End If
 Next i
```

The error is triggered by the RemoveItem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `.RowSource` to fill your ListBox you cannot remove list items from the list.

Therefore you need to fill your list using `LstWSource.AddItem`. Loop through your range and add each item to your ListBox based on your criteria. Also see [Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @PEH

Comment: I do the checking.

Answer (score 0):

For additional information and bring my definite solution related to slowing populating : I used once the read of Range cells to populate a dynamic array. Then, I use this array to exclude or include lines in another second array.

These are lines to be considered :

```
J = 1
For i = LBound(G_varListYears) To UBound(G_varListYears)

If G_varListYears(i) <= CStr(Year(G_datJourTraitee)) Then
  '>>>
  ReDim Preserve vListTMP(J)
  vListTMP(J) = G_varListYears(i)
  J = J + 1
  '>>
ElseIf (Me.chkNextYear = True) And ((Month(G_datJourTraitee) = 11 Or Month(G_datJourTraitee) = 12) And (G_varListYears(i) = CStr(Year(G_datJourTraitee) + 1))) Then
  '>>>
  ReDim Preserve vListTMP(J)
  vListTMP(J) = G_varListYears(i)
  J = J + 1
  '>>
Else
  '>>
End If

Next i

With Me.LstWSource
  .ColumnWidths = "28pt"
  .List = vListTMP()
  .ListIndex = -1
End With '>>>
```

Hope it'll help too.