# How to change display value in ListBox? RowSource

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

As a source of data for my ListBox, I have specifed named range (RowSource - Dimension). However, instead of actual values in a ListBox, I want to have custom display values.

[image: example]

I trying to change Value in Appearance tab but I get an error "Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value"

How can I make "60" be displayed as "High"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)

Comment: I don't think so. I don't want to add items to listbox. I simply want to change display value.

Comment: It doesnt work like that. you need 2 columns, and then you set the width of one column to zero to hide it. See the `ColumnWidths` property? try setting it to `0px; 100px"