# Fillter a multi column listbox based on a Textbox value

Tags: vba, filter, listbox

I've been using the following code for quite a while and it works just perfectly to filter a listbox based on a Textbox value (code by Ralph).

```
    Private Sub Textbox1_Change()

Dim i As Long
Dim arrList As Variant

Me.ListBox1.Clear
If TMP.Range("A" & TMP.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row > 1 And Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value) <> vbNullString Then
    arrList = TMP.Range("A1:A" & TMP.Range("A" & TMP.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For i = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
        If InStr(1, arrList(i, 1), Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value), vbTextCompare) Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
        End If
    Next i
End If
If Me.ListBox1.ListCount = 1 Then Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True

End Sub
```

I would like to use it with multicolumn Listbox (4 to be accurate A->D). One of the hints in the original post (titled "How to filter listbox values based on a Textbox value") was to replace :

```
Me.ListBox1.AddItem arrList(i, 1)
```

with

```
Me.Listbox.AddItem 
Listbox.List(0, 0) = arrList(i, 1) 
Listbox.List(0, 1) = arrList(i, 2)
```

but i can't make it work. I've been stuck on this for days, could you help me get it to work?

Thank you...

Comment: What happens when you try the mentioned suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding items in a Listbox with multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns)

Comment: As soon as i try to type something in Textbox i get the message: "Method or data member not found"