Using a ComboBox to filter a ListBox
I have a ListBox that displays every record entered to my database sheet. I want to filter these records using a ComboBox that matches values from a specific column. This column stores an area. I populated the ComboBox with all the areas but when I choose an area to display records with this specific area, I get an error.
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    
    Dim areas() As String
    areas = Split("Assy, PPW, Coils, THS, THP, M/A, Machine Center, Tool Room, Maintenance", ", ")
    
    Dim area As Variant
    For Each area In areas
        cmbAreaFilter.AddItem area
        
    Next area
    
End Sub

Private Sub cmbAreaFilter_Change()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = cmbAreaFilter.Value Then
            With frmOpenRecords.lstOpenRecords
                .AddItem
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(i, "E").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 7) = ws.Cells(i, "H").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 8) = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 9) = ws.Cells(i, "J").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 10) = ws.Cells(i, "K").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 11) = ws.Cells(i, "L").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 12) = ws.Cells(i, "M").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 13) = ws.Cells(i, "N").Value
                
            End With
        End If
    Next i
          
End Sub

The code above is what I have to try and make the ComboBox work. The error message I get when I choose an area in the ComboBox is this: "Permission Denied". And when I click debug it highlights this line ".AddItem". I would appreciate if someone can help fix this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973287/adding-items-in-a-listbox-with-multiple-columns

It's much safer to use With Me.lstOpenRecords than With frmOpenRecords.lstOpenRecords   In the running instance of the form Me always references that instance.

You can't use AddItem if you filled the listbox from a range: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/589106-combobox-using-additem-permission-denied.html#:~:text=When%20a%20Combobox%20is%20filled,the%20range%20on%20the%20Worksheet.

Do you have a value in  RowSource property ?

Here's one way to do what you want: it's quicker to read the data into a 2D array when loading the userform than to access cell-by-cell when loading the listbox.
Option Explicit

Dim data 'a 2D array of the list data from the worksheet

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim lst
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    lst = FilterArray(data, 2, CLng(Me.ComboBox1.Value))
    If Not IsEmpty(lst) Then Me.ListBox1.list = lst
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'get the listbox data as an array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
        data = .Range("A2:N" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    End With
    Me.ListBox1.list = data 'initial listbox fill

    'fill the combobox with all unique values from (eg) second column
    Me.ComboBox1.list = UniquesFromColumn(data, 2)
    '...or use a pre-determined list
    'Me.ComboBox1.list = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20) 
End Sub

'extract all unique values from the 2D array `data`,
'   in the specified column position `colNum`
Function UniquesFromColumn(data, colNum As Long)
    Dim dict As Object, r As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        dict(data(r, colNum)) = True
    Next r
    UniquesFromColumn = dict.Keys()
End Function

'return a 2D array of rows from `data`, filtered where value
'  in column# `colNum` matches `colVal`
Function FilterArray(data, colNum As Long, colVal) As Variant
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long, lst
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        If data(r, colNum) = colVal Then n = n + 1
    Next r
    If n > 0 Then
        ReDim lst(0 To n - 1, 0 To UBound(data, 2) - 1)
        n = 0
        For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
            If data(r, colNum) = colVal Then
                For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
                    lst(n, c - 1) = data(r, c)
                Next c
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next r
    End If
    FilterArray = lst
End Function


Use the following code to fill the ComboBox;
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim areas As Variant
    
    areas = Array("Assy", "PPW", "Coils", "THS", "THP", "M/A", "Machine Center", "Tool Room", "Maintenance")
    cmbAreaFilter.List = areas
End Sub


(1) There are 3 ways to fill a Listbox:
By setting a range to the property RowSource - in that case the content of the range is filled into the combo box.
By filling it manually using addItem
But if you have a RowSource set and you call AddItem, you will get a runtime error 70 "Permission denied". You will need to remove the RowSource definition, either by removing it from the properties at design time, or by adding the statement .RowSource = "" before the first AddItem.
A third way is by assigning a 2-dimensional array to the List-property of the ListBox. In that case, the RowSource-property will be removed automatically. The answer of Tim Williams shows how to do it.
(2) If you fill the Listbox using a row source, it can have an unlimited number (at least 100) of columns.
However, if you fill it with AddItem, you have a maximum of 10 columns (0..9). You can define a higher number at ColumnCount, but using .List(.ListCount - 1, 10) (or higher) will create a runtime error 380 "Could not set the list property. Invalid property value". There is no way around this.
If you will fill it with a 2-dimensional array that has more than 10 columns, you will get no runtime error, but only the first 10 columns are shown.
(3) If you use AddItem, don't forget to clear the ListBox before you fill it, else you will add new items to the ListBox over and over again. Using a 2-dimensional array will clear the old list automatically.
Private Sub fillCombo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
    
    With Me.lstOpenRecords
        .RowSource = ""  ' Remove row source if set. 
        .Clear           ' Remove items if any.
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If ws.Cells(i, "B").Value = cmbAreaFilter.Value Then
                .AddItem
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 0) = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = ws.Cells(i, "D").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 4) = ws.Cells(i, "E").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 5) = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 6) = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 7) = ws.Cells(i, "H").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 8) = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value
                .List(.ListCount - 1, 9) = ws.Cells(i, "J").Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub


Maybe worth adding the only way to get headers is to use RowSource to populate the listbox.
